# jquery sort element with array value without html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think there may be a new way to sort them without an attribute
but I'm not getting it to work properly. Who can help me understand why?

Initially I create an array, I put the various elements in the correct order.

```js
var order = [4,3,2,7,5,0,1,6,8];
var i = 0;

$.fn.formordina = function(selector){
    (selector ? this.find(selector) : this).parent().each(function(){
       
$(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
   return order[i++];
        }).detach().appendTo(this);
    });

    return this;
};

$(".form-action ol").formordina('li');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-action">
<ol>
<li>banana</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>tomato</li>
<li>kiwi</li>
<li>pear</li>
<li>peach</li>
<li>lemon</li>
<li>ginger</li>
<li>orange</li>
</ol>

</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what your trying to accomplish here. `.sort()` can use a compare function, yet it's expecting `-1`, `0`, or `1` to be returned. Please clarify your request.

Comment: This question might be what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781765/js-sort-by-specific-sort-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you some. If you have a specific Sort order you want for the list, you may want to pass it in as an Option. Then collect the Items, organize the, flush the current list, and replace them with the new order.

```js
$.fn.formordina = function(options) {
  console.log("Options", options);
  var listItems = this.find(options.items);
  var newList = {};
  $.each(options.order, function(k, v) {
    newList[k] = listItems.eq(v - 1)[0];
  });
  $(this).html("");
  console.log(newList);
  $(this).append(newList);
};

$(function() {
  $(".form-action ol").formordina({
    items: "> li",
    order: [4, 3, 2, 7, 5, 0, 1, 6, 8]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-action">
  <ol>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>tomato</li>
    <li>kiwi</li>
    <li>pear</li>
    <li>peach</li>
    <li>lemon</li>
    <li>ginger</li>
    <li>orange</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.